# initWithRootViewController and pushViewController (UINavigationController)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` that I init with my own `UIViewController` as its root. I've noticed that it is not resizing it's view to fit in the bounds of the navigation view controller. It pushes it down. The documentation for `pushViewController:animated:` says that it resizes the view automatically, but the same is not said for `initWithRootViewController:`. What do I need to do to get it to automatically resize it to fit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the nav controller displays the root view controller, the root view controller's view will be sized to fit between the navbar and the toolbar (if any). This is automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the image you are getting which shows your view is pushes down.

As per the navigation controller your view will pushes down about 44 pixcel in the screen due to navigation bar of the navigation controller.

Set the view property in the xib to attach the navigation bar on the screen so that you can check your view when you push it through navigation controller.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The view controller's view was being resize correctly but a subview of that view was not. Thanks!

Comment: hi @FrankWeindel I encounter the same issue with you, could you tell me how to fix it?